# Setup MTS MBLAZE in Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, kubuntu, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I have kubuntu 16.04 and i am trying to setup my MTS Mblaze mobile broadband.

There is no notification of any kind when i insert the usb device.
But lsusb is detecting the device

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 19d2:fff5 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
```

And the output of dmesg is :

```
121.915983] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  122.046011] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=fff5
[  122.046015] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[  122.046016] usb 1-3: Product: ZTE CDMA Tech
[  122.046017] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: ZTE, Incorporated
[  122.046019] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 80a0c53d0000
[  122.201009] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  122.201080] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[  122.201148] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  122.206857] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  123.203151] scsi 3:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ZTE      USB Storage FFFE 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  123.203502] scsi 3:0:0:1: Direct-Access     ZTE      USB Storage FFFE 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  123.206633] sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
[  123.206636] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[  123.206817] sr 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[  123.206889] sr 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[  123.207095] sd 3:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  123.210825] sd 3:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Now i tried adding a new mobile broadband connection and gave all the correct settings, including the username password.

Now i save the connection and disconnect and reinsert the device, and i click the network icon and can't see any mobile broadband connections.

I have no idea, if there should be an enable mobile broadband setting or something, but i have no idea what to do now.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT :**

I tried using usb_modeswitch and this is what i got:

```
can't use storage command in MessageContent with interface 0;
   interface class is 255, expected 8. Abort
```

Which raises the suspiscion that my modem has already swithced to the modem mode.

But i still can't see any mobile broadband connections in my network manager. And there is no option called **Enable Mobile Broadband** like in the gnome network manager when i had ubuntu

**EDIT 2:**
I removed and inserted my dongle a few times and then lsusb gave something different :

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 19d2:fff5 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
```

You can see the Product id has changed from fffe to fff5.

Now i ran usb_modeswitch with the following configuration file:

```
DefaultVendor=0x19d2;
DefaultProduct=0xfff5;
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```

The output was:

```
Read config file: /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/19d2:fff5.conf

* usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
* Version 2.2.5 (C) Josua Dietze 2015
* Based on libusb1/libusbx

! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x19d2
DefaultProduct= 0xfff5
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
NeedResponse=0

InquireDevice=1

Look for default devices ...
found USB ID 1d6b:0003
found USB ID 04f2:b50c
found USB ID 8087:07dc
found USB ID 19d2:fff5
vendor ID matched
product ID matched
found USB ID 1d6b:0002
Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 008 on bus 001
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
Use endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)
Inquire device details; driver will be detached ...
Looking for active driver ...
No active driver found. Detached before or never attached

SCSI inquiry data (for identification)
-------------------------
Vendor String: ZTE     
Model String: USB Storage FFFE
Revision String: 2.31
-------------------------

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: ZTE, Incorporated
    Product: ZTE CDMA Tech
Serial No.: 80a0c53d0000
-------------------------
Set up interface 0
Use endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
OK, message successfully sent
Reset response endpoint 0x81
Reset message endpoint 0x01
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!
```

Even after this there was no new connection in my network manager.

**EDIT 3:**

When the product id is **fffe**
mmcli -L gives :

```
Found 1 modems:
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [ZTEMT INCORPORATED] AC2792
```

and mmcli -m 0 gives:

```
/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 (device id 'bda7d8378866c892ed4c1eed78be4aec3c993c16')
-------------------------
Hardware |   manufacturer: 'ZTEMT INCORPORATED'
        |          model: 'AC2792'
        |       revision: 'AC2792YU8AD511'
        |      supported: 'cdma-evdo'
        |        current: 'cdma-evdo'
        |   equipment id: '80A0C53D'
-------------------------
System   |         device: '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3'
        |        drivers: 'option1'
        |         plugin: 'ZTE'
        |   primary port: 'ttyUSB0'
        |          ports: 'ttyUSB0 (at), ttyUSB1 (at), ttyUSB3 (qcdm)'
-------------------------
Numbers  |           own : '8645921832'
-------------------------
Status   |           lock: 'none'
        | unlock retries: 'unknown'
        |          state: 'enabled'
        |    power state: 'on'
        |    access tech: 'unknown'
        | signal quality: '0' (cached)
-------------------------
Modes    |      supported: 'allowed: 2g; preferred: none
        |                  allowed: 3g; preferred: none
        |                  allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: none
        |                  allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 2g
        |                  allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 3g'
        |        current: 'allowed: any; preferred: none'
-------------------------
Bands    |      supported: 'unknown'
        |        current: 'unknown'
-------------------------
IP       |      supported: 'ipv4'
-------------------------
CDMA     |           meid: 'unknown'
        |            esn: '80A0C53D'
        |            sid: 'unknown'
        |            nid: 'unknown'
        |   registration: CDMA1x 'unknown'
        |                 EV-DO  'unknown'
        |     activation: 'unknown'
-------------------------
SIM      |           path: 'none'

-------------------------
Bearers  |          paths: 'none'
```

and journaltct -u NetworkManager gives:

```
May 15 22:13:32 vikash-HP-ENVY-Notebook NetworkManager[800]: <info>  [1463330612.9359] (ttyUSB0): modem state changed, 'disabled' --> 'enabling' (reason: user preference)
May 15 22:13:32 vikash-HP-ENVY-Notebook NetworkManager[800]: <info>  [1463330612.9366] manager: (ttyUSB0): new Broadband device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
May 15 22:13:32 vikash-HP-ENVY-Notebook NetworkManager[800]: <info>  [1463330612.9368] device (ttyUSB0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
May 15 22:13:32 vikash-HP-ENVY-Notebook NetworkManager[800]: <info>  [1463330612.9370] device (ttyUSB0): modem state 'enabling'
May 15 22:13:32 vikash-HP-ENVY-Notebook NetworkManager[800]: <warn>  [1463330612.9371] (ttyUSB0): failed to retrieve SIM object: No SIM object available
May 15 22:13:33 vikash-HP-ENVY-Notebook NetworkManager[800]: <info>  [1463330613.1179] (ttyUSB0): modem state changed, 'enabling' --> 'enabled' (reason: user-requested)
May 15 22:14:28 vikash-HP-ENVY-Notebook NetworkManager[800]: <info>  [1463330668.2189] WWAN hardware radio set disabled
May 15 22:14:28 vikash-HP-ENVY-Notebook NetworkManager[800]: <info>  [1463330668.2191] (ttyUSB0): modem state changed, 'enabled' --> 'disabling' (reason: user preference)
May 15 22:14:28 vikash-HP-ENVY-Notebook NetworkManager[800]: <info>  [1463330668.2192] audit: op="radio-control" arg="wwan-enabled:0" pid=1243 uid=1000 result="success"
May 15 22:14:28 vikash-HP-ENVY-Notebook NetworkManager[800]: <info>  [1463330668.2266] (ttyUSB0): modem state changed, 'disabling' --> 'disabled' (reason: user-requested)
May 15 22:14:30 vikash-HP-ENVY-Notebook NetworkManager[800]: <info>  [1463330670.6392] WWAN hardware radio set enabled
May 15 22:14:30 vikash-HP-ENVY-Notebook NetworkManager[800]: <info>  [1463330670.6393] (ttyUSB0): modem state changed, 'disabled' --> 'enabling' (reason: user preference)
May 15 22:14:30 vikash-HP-ENVY-Notebook NetworkManager[800]: <info>  [1463330670.6393] audit: op="radio-control" arg="wwan-enabled:1" pid=1243 uid=1000 result="success"
May 15 22:14:30 vikash-HP-ENVY-Notebook NetworkManager[800]: <info>  [1463330670.7565] (ttyUSB0): modem state changed, 'enabling' --> 'enabled' (reason: user-requested)
```

Howevewer if i remove and reinsert the dongle a few times the product id changes to **fff5** and mmcli -L does not find any modems.

But then in either scneario i have no idea actually how to connect to the internet since nothing shows up in the Network Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

Install `gnome-ppp` and connect your modem. It is the best way to connect to the Internet. Although, it is developed to be run on `Gnome` but I've been using this program on my `Kubuntu 14.04` for a long time. So, I think it should work on yours too.

```
1. Install gnome-ppp by:
    apt-get install gnome-ppp

2. Then run the program by executing the following in the terminal:
    gnome-ppp

3. The application will start. Then verify that gnome-ppp has correctly detected the modem: click on "Parameters" and later on "Detect"

4. In the Gnome-ppp window, fill login, password and telephone number of the Internet Service Provider.

5. If you get an "immediate" disconnection: in "Parameters" / "Options", unmark "check carrier line"

6. To connect, you must be in the gnome-ppp window. Click in "Connect".

7. When the IPs appear in the terminal, the connection is established.

8. When you are connect, appears a little window. You can click in "details" to see information about the connection.
```

Alternatively, you can also use `kppp` for `kubuntu` if `gnome-ppp` doesn't works for you. To install `kppp` simply type:

```
apt-get install kppp
```

`kppp` was developed for `kubuntu` only. It has a nice graphical interface too. But I've never used it so cannot provide you with instructions for it.

**Method 2**

1. Connect the modem with the PC. The system will detect the device automatically.
2. Look out for the notification saying Device recognized USB Modem, ONDA Communication S.p.A., then click on the icon of Network Connections in system tray.
3. You will find an option New Mobile Broadband (CDMA) Connection, click on it.
4. A new window will open to setup a mobile broadband connection. Click Forward button
5. Select `India` as country, then Forward,
6. Select `MTS MBlaze` from the providers’ list, Forward,
7. And then click Apply,
8. Now Disconnect the connection which is trying to connect automatically. Because it is not going work until we provide username and password.
9. Open `Edit Connections`->`Mobile Broadband (Tab)`->Select `MTS MBlaze Connection` and click on `Edit`.
10. Under Mobile Broadband, type `internet@internet.mtsindia.in` as username and `MTS` as password.

[image]

11. Check Available to all users and Connect automatically if you want.
12. Save it and close Network Connections.
13. Now take off the modem from the port and reconnect it.
14. After the modem get recognised by the system, try to connect Internet.
15. If everything goes right, you will see that your Internet connection will get connected.

[image]

**Method 3**

Simply download [this](https://rapidshare.com/files/514013822/CrossPlatformUI-V2.1.2-SSTL-ALL-ubuntu.deb) package and install this after connecting the modem. It might work. This is a driver for `MTS Mblaze` modems.

**Method 4**

This is a simple automated shell script to install mts mblaze UI automatically in your linux .The installation script will setup everything but you just need to choose some options (interactively) from setup. It can work for all Linux desktops environments.

```
#!/bin/bash   
echo "
echo "MTS MBLAZE WIRELESSS DATA USB MODEM TERMINAL INSTALLATION GUIDE"
echo ""
echo "Select model for your MTS MBLAZE modem"
sleep 2
echo ""
echo "There are two types of modem "
echo "
 `printf "1"``echo ""` MTS-MBLAZE-MINI"
 `printf "2"``echo ""` MTS -MBLAZE-ULTRA"
echo ""
sleep 1
echo "Type (1 to 2): "
while read Input
do
# for mts-mblaze-mini

if [ $Input = "1" ]; then
{
echo "You have selcted MTS-MBLAZE-MINI"
sleep 1
echo "starting installation.................. "
sleep 1
echo "Downloading and installing ............"
sleep 2
cd && wget -O Linux.zip     https://www.dropbox.com/s/2osuilo99kc3h15/Linux.zip?dl=0
unzip -o Linux.zip -d $HOME/
rm Linux.zip
cd && wget -O install_linux.sh     https://www.dropbox.com/s/jk0wrpcok02r6wt/install_linux.sh?dl=0
cd && chmod +x install_linux.sh && ./install_linux.sh
}
break;
# for mts-mblaze-ultra

elif [ $Input = "2" ]; then
{
echo "You have selcted MTS-MBLAZE-ULTRA"
sleep 1
echo " starting installation................"
sleep 1
echo "Downloading and installing ....."
sleep 2
cd && wget -O Linuxx.zip https://www.dropbox.com/s/yirj4d1cpet1i1a/Linuxx.zip?dl=0
unzip -o Linuxx.zip -d $HOME/
rm Linuxx.zip
cd && wget -O install_linux2.sh     https://www.dropbox.com/s/tuggjr3jqdnlwil/install_linux2.sh?dl=0
cd && chmod +x install_linux2.sh && ./install_linux2.sh
}
break;
else
echo "Input is invalid!!!"
echo "Type right model of modem."
echo ""
echo "Type from (1 to 2): "
fi # closed
done # all done
```

To install MTS Mblaze UI in Debian/Ubuntu/Linux Mint/deepin/LMDE/Any Linux Distribution open terminal (Press Ctrl+Alt+T) and copy the following commands in the Terminal:

```
cd && wget -O mts.sh https://www.dropbox.com/s/wi4xkrg31ii76me/mts.sh?dl=0
cd && chmod +x mts.sh && ./mts.sh
```

**source:** https://emilgeorgejames.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/a-script-to-automate-installing-mts-mblaze-ui-in-linux/

Comment: will the network manager detect the connection? because many apps like the software centre depend on it.

Comment: Yes, it will. You won't have any problem, if this works for you.

Comment: No luck, kppp fails at initializing modem, and gnome-ppp doesn't detect a modem at all even though modem manager detects a modem

Comment: Well, i reinstalled my network manager and method 2 now works , kind of automatic detection, so i will mark yours as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Another good way of connecting to internet through 3g modems or dongles is [Sakis3G](http://www.sakis3g.com/#howto). Although you need to have ppp installed first but it solves many problems. You can try your luck with this package.